# Regex $1-$9 production use

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it safe to use ‘$1-$9’ in production? On MDN it gives a warning about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n

Is there a difference between

```
    str.replace(/[a-z]/g, $1, $2)
```

Or

```
    regex.$1
    regex.$2
```

Comment: If the documentation says it's not smart to use it, maybe you shouldn't use it? How well do you know the browsers your users will use?

Comment: We are using all of them

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid at all:

```
str.replace(/[a-z]/g, $1, $2)
```

`String.prototype.replace()` only takes two arguments: the regular expression and the replacement. You can't have two replacement strings.

`$1`, `$2`, etc. are normally only used inside a replacement string, e.g.

```
str.replace(/([a-z])-(\d)/g, "$1 $2")
```

If you want to use `$1`, `$2`, outside the replacement string, they aren't global variables, they're properties of the `RegExp` object that was used to do the matching.

```
var re = /([a-z])-(\d)/;
re.exec(str);
console.log(re.$1, re.$2);
```

But there's little reason to do this. `re.exec` returns an array containing the capture groups, so you can do:

```
match = re.exec(str);
console.log(match[1], match[2]);
```

This is the standard-conforming way to access capture groups, so there's no good reason to use the non-standard properties.